# Continue batch code after calling vb script from bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I have a code where I use vb script to send email from a particular folder on my computer. After sending email I would like to execute the rest of the code of the bat file. But when email is sent the rest of the code does not execute.:

.bat file:

```
cd\
D:
call D:\folder\AbatFile.bat
pushd %~dp0
start /wait "" /b cscript sendemail.vbs D:\folder\afile.csv
cd\
D:
call D:\folder\anotheBatchfile.bat
```

In my code above the statment - `call D:\folder\anotheBatchfile.bat` does not execute. How can I make the batch file execution continue after the vbscript call is done.

Comment: Have you tried without the `/B` switch of `start`?

Comment: Post the sendmail.vbs script. Replace sensitive information with "xxxxx"

Answer (score -1):

instead of

```
start /wait "" /b cscript sendemail.vbs D:\folder\afile.csv
```

try this

```
cscript sendemail.vbs D:\folder\afile.csv
```

Comment: that does not make sense. unless the cscript command hung, `call D:\folder\anotheBatchfile.bat` will certainly be executed. how you know it did not run? can you provide the actual content of `anotheBatchfile.bat` ?